# Use a custom URL to get a customized printable version of Google Calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to print a week's worth of Google Calendar events from the command line.  I figure using https://www.google.com/calendar/printable rather than some API is the easiest way to do that.  I need some help with the arguments though. In the command below, what do each of the arguments mean?

https://www.google.com/calendar/printable?mode=MONTH&wkst=1&hl=en&pgsz=letter&dates=20090801%2F20100531&src=fla-general@forestlake.org&ctz=%3Csomething%3E&src=fla-general@forestlake.org&pfs=NORMAL&po=AUTO&psdec=true&pbw=false&pjs=false&rand=%3Csomething%3E&pda=true

Where is the documentation I can read up concerning this?

**Argument list:**

```
mode=
wkst=
hl=
pgsz=
dates=
src=
ctz=
src=
pfs=
po=
psdec=
pbw=
pjs=
rand=
pda=
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html seems helpful

Answer (score 7):

I do not find any Google documentation for the parameters, but [this blog post](http://wiert.me/2010/06/28/google-calendar-printing-multiple-months-or-weeks-to-pdf/) documents most of them.

- **mode**: Mode parameter (mode) must be either AGENDA, DAY, WEEK or MONTH
- **wkst**: Week start parameter (wkst) must be between 1 (Sunday) and 7
  (Saturday)
- **hl**: is a language code from [this list](http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1)
- **pgsz**: letter, a4 (others?)
- **po**: page orientation AUTO, PORTRAIT, LANDSCAPE
- **ctz**: time zone, eg "Europe/Amsterdam", a list of time zones is [here](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/4105).
- **pfs**: font size: SMALLEST, SMALLER, SMALL, NORMAL, BIG, BIGGER,
  BIGGEST
- **pbw**: print black and white, values are true, false
- **psdec**: Show events you have declined, values are true, false
- **pjs**: Insert “Print JavaScript” into the PDF (true) or just loads the
  PDF (false)
- **pda**: Prepare the PDF for download (true) or printing (false)
- **dates**: the start and ending date both ISO 8601 encoded as YYYYMMDD,
  separated by a / (which ends up as %2F when URL-encoded)
- **src**: calendar id.  Pass multiple src parameters to include multiple
  calendars.

Comment: The **mode** parameter can also be DAY, for single day display (or "day", lowercase is ok).

Comment: @KaiCarver I've updated the blog post accordingly. Thanks Guy for referring to the blog post.